# Reformatting date inputted from a html form before collecting it in $_POST in php

Tags: php, html, sql, date, where-clause

I have this html form which asks user to choose a date (input type= "date"), which is in the format `dd/mm/yyyy` (which I guess is due to my browser), and I am collecting that input in a variable in another .php file using the $_POST ($date1=$_POST("date")]. I have to use $date1 for further comparisons (using it inside a `where` clause) given the dates in my table are in `yyyy-mm-dd` format.

Suggest me some method by which I can reformat the html form input date to the desired form. Or is there any other way to do it?

I'm a newbie, don't panic if you feel that the question has already been asked, one can always scroll down :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this :

```
$date=strtotime($_POST['date']);
$date=date('Y-m-d',$date);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$datetime = strtotime($_POST("date"));
$mysqldate = date("d-m-Y", $datetime);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [DateTime::createFromFormat](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php). You can then reformat the date to any other format you desire.

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $_POST('date'));
$date = $date->format('Y-m-d');
```

Answer (score 0):

use [strtotime()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) with [date()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)

```
echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s',strtotime($_POST['date']));
```